# Customize parts of my control

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, win-universal-app

I’m working on a universal window SDK.

The SDK’s main entry point is a UserControl-derived class that exposes some functionality.

We’re not allowing our users to change the appearance completely, that’s why I don’t like CustomControl + generic.xaml  + template parts approach.

However, there’re some child items we’d like to allow customize. Like three different buttons that are part of our control. I want to provide sensible default styles/templates/content, but I want my users to be able to redesign those child items completely, in case they want to. Or, just change e.g. background color, if they want to do that.

What’s the best way?

1. Expose (dependency?) properties of my control `Style Button1Style` ?
2. Expose (dependency?) properties of my control `ControlTemplate Button1Template` ?
3. Expose (dependency?) properties of my control `DataTemplate Button1ContentTemplate` ?
4. A combination of those?
5. Some other way?

The SDK is portable, need to support Windows 8.1 and 10, both Store and Phones.

**Update**: I know dependency properties are required for data bindings to work. What I don’t know whether my users will use data bindings or they wont.
I don’t need animations.

The use cases I’m expecting are following:

1. Most customers should be happy with default appearance –  for them I only need to provide sensible default look.
2. Some will want to change a color or margin of some child controls.
3. Some will replace our icons with their custom ones.
4. Some will completely rework our button’s styles and templates.

I want to allow them to do 2-4 in MS Blend, in XAML only. How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implemented #1, works more of less OK.

1. Style/template those parts, put those styles/templates in a separate resource dictionary "DefaultStyles".
2. Create a [code behind for that resource dictionary](http://www.reflectionit.nl/blog/2015/windows-xaml-tips-resourcedictionary-with-codebehind). This is done to avoid that crazy "ms-appx:///" URIs and instead reference dictionary by class name.
3. In user control code, add several dependency properties of type "Style" for customizable parts of my control.
4. In user control code, in constructor, set data context of the root element of the control (but not the control itself) to `this`.
5. In user control XAML, include DefaultStyles resources:

   ```
   <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
       <local:DefaultStyles />
   </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
   ```
6. In user control XAML, reference that styles: `<Button Style="{Binding MyButtonStyle, TargetNullValue={StaticResource MyButtonDefaultStyle}}" />` where `MyButtonStyle` is dependency property created in step #3, `MyButtonDefaultStyle` is default style created in step #1
7. In client app's page:

   ```
   <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
       <sdk:DefaultStyles />
   </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
   <!-- Debug code: override a single property -->
   <Style x:Key="sss" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource MyButtonDefaultStyle}">
       <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
   </Style>
   ```
8. Finally, in client app's page:

   ```
   <sdk:TheControl MyButtonStyle={StaticResource sss} />
   ```

This way, everything works out of the box, my users are able to adjust a single margin or color without copy-pasting pages of XAML, or completely ignore styles/templates I've provided and create their own ones.

I wonder is there a simpler way?

The task "Allow user to override styles, partially or completely" doesn't sound like it should be that hard to accomplish.

**Update:** For some reason, on windows phone 8.1, you can't set `Content` property in style (no errors, just no effect). Fortunately, you can instead set `ContentTemplate` property, which seems to work on all platforms.

Answer (score 0):

@Soonts, there are a lot of variables here. And, though many of the StackOverflow nerds get really worked up over developers asking multiple questions in one question, I think we can work together to get your answer(s).

First, I think you should review my article on this subject. It focuses on two-way binding in a user control which, admittedly, is trick.

> http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2013/07/solved-two-way-binding-inside-user.html

Second, I think it is important to understand ControlTemplate binding, property animation and binding, and DataTemplate scopes. I speak pretty deeply on this topic in a course  @ Microsoft Virtual Academy.

> https://mva.microsoft.com/en-us/training-courses/xaml-for-windows-10-controls-14482

A short answer to most of your questions is that Dependency Properties are what you need. Because you tagged your question with Windows 8, it's important that you leverage the changed event defined in the property metadata. Again, this is in the article.

Finally, I have written a significant control deriving from user control, so I can confirm that what you are wanting to accomplish is certainly possible. If you want to look over my code and see if we are doing anything you want to steal, you can do that, too.

> https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/blob/master/Template10%20(Library)/Controls/HamburgerMenu.xaml.cs

Best of luck.

Comment: Hi. I’ve clarified my question. Basically, I don’t know _what_ to expose, not how.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, you have changed your question. Here you go.

Here's how I have done it in the past.

```
<UserControl>
    <Grid Background="{x:Bind MyBackground, FallbackValue=White}">
        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind MyText, FallbackValue=DesigntimeValue }" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

> Please note that {x:Bind} does not support designtime values, so using FallBackValue is basically giving you the designetime value. Don't confuse this with your default value.

Then this code-behind:

```
public sealed partial class MyUserControl : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MyUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    Brush _MyBackground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
    public Brush MyBackground { get { return _MyBackground; } set { Set(ref _MyBackground, value); } }

    string _MyText = "Default value";
    public string MyText { get { return _MyText; } set { Set(ref _MyText, value); } }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    void Set<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (!Equals(storage, value))
        {
            storage = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName);
        }
    }

    void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) =>
       PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

    #endregion  
}
```

> This is just how we implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in Template 10 (http://aka.ms/template10). You can implement it however you like.

And use it like this:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <local:MyUserControl MyBackground="Yellow" MyText="JerryNixon" />
</Grid>
```

> The default values is what you will see in the designtime of your app, not the fallback. FallBackValues will be what you see when designing the user control itself.

It's worth pointing out that you can replace any of these properties with dependency properties. The only reason you would want to do that is if you intended them to be animated.

I hope this helps. Best of luck.

Comment: Your approach only works for trivial controls like in your sample, with one grid and one textblock. It does not allow to completely rework our button’s styles and templates. And I’ve listed that requirement in my question.

I’ve already figured out the solution, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35166504/126995
If you know better way, I’ll happily replace it with something simpler.